# Perform a for() loop to replace those elements of vec_tor that are greater than "5" with the number "5"

Tags: r

Perform a `for()` loop to replace those elements of vector that are greater than "5" with the number "5".
#can use the functions `for()` and `seq_along()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It doesn't need a loop though

```
vec_tor[vec_tor > 5] <- 5
```

Or in `replace`

```
replace(vec_tor, vec_tor > 5, 5)
```

Or with `pmin`

```
pmin(vec_tor, 5)
```

---

In a `for` loop, it would be

```
for(i in seq_along(vec_tor)) {
    if(vec_tor[i] > 5) {
        vec_tor[i] <- 5
     }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. vec_tor is not named

Comment: @zcw I assume the object name as `vec_tor` based on the descriptoin in the post `replace those elements of vec_tor`

Comment: Thanks for your help. And is it possible to use sapply() loop in this problem?

Comment: @zcw yes, it is possible, but isn't your question about `for` loop and `seq_along`

Comment: And use ifelse() for the question

Comment: @zcw with `ifelse`, you need `ifelse(vec_tor > 5, 5, vec_tor)`

Comment: Yeah, it's work. where I can accept the solution

Comment: may I know how can I use a sapply loop in this question?